# Identifying duplicate values across two worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have two worksheets, one which contains historical data and one which contains data I have just imported. I would like to check the existing data to see if the new data contains any duplicate quotes (which would therefore have been "converted" into orders).

Currently I am taking the quote number in A2 and comparing it to the quote numbers in the other worksheet using the following code:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Dim wS As Worksheet
Set wS = ActiveSheet
Dim importWS as worksheet
importWS = sheets.("NEWDATA")

select.importWS
Range("A1").Select
Do
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

'Set the current quote number as a value to be located
Dim valueToFind As Long
valueToFind = ActiveCell.Value
Dim checkRange As Range
Set checkRange = wS.Range("D1:D" & EntryRow)

'Check the existing worksheet to see if the quote already exists
Dim xlCell As Range
For Each xlCell In checkRange
    If xlCell.Value = valueToFind Then



problems:    

        Dim existQuote As range
        existQuote = xlCell.Address
        Dim existingRow As Integer
        existingRow = existingQuote.Row

        MsgBox valueToFind & "in row" & existingRow & "has been converted to an order"


    End If
Next xlCell


Loop Until ActiveCell.Value > 300000 Or ActiveCell.Value = ""

ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select
Dim DataPoints As Integer
DataPoints = ActiveCell.Row
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
```

I am having problems with the if function at "problems:"
The code successfully identifies that quote numbers which are duplicated, but I would like it to be check if another cell in the same row = "sales order" and then perform an action based on this.

I cannot think of a way to get the row number of the cell I am in using this code, so that I can check it and edit the entry.

**EDIT: The `.address` function returns a `string`, not a `range`. This was why it was failing.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually ended up using the find function to do this in a manner which used the least resources.

Answer (score 0):

There a couple of general comments I would suggest thinking about to start off with, though they may not solve the problem. I must admit I haven't downloaded your workbook so apologies if you've already done this in bits of code you haven't posted.

a. It's probably good rigor to start the module with `Option Explicit`. From the code posted here, it looks like you introduce an un-`Dim`ed variable, `transfer`, right where the problem starts. You also seem to create a variable `EntryRow` - possibly you mean the EntireRow function? Here's a piece of code demonstrating the need for `Option Explicit`

```
Dim existingQuote As Variant      
    transfer = xlCell.Address
        Dim existQuote As
        existQuote = transfer
        Dim existingRow As Integer
        existingRow = existingQuote.Row
```

You `Dim`ed the variant `existingQuote`, created an un-`Dim`ed variable `transfer`, `Dim`ed `existQuote` without data type, and then try to assign the value of the variable `existingRow` to `existingQuote.row` without `Set`ing what the `existingQuote` variant array variable should contain.

b. Why not go straight to stuff? If you want to select cell A2 in `importWS` and do something to it/get something from it, what about

```
valueToFind = importWS.Range("A2").Value
```

This at least may help make the code easier to read, although I have the (possibly superstitious) feeling that the macros also seem a little bit faster

c. I would also recommend destroying variables at the end of a subroutine.

If you clear up your code, it may also help the forum boffins to get to grips with what you're trying to do.

**EDIT**: (Untested)

How about this:

```
Dim xlCell As Excel.Range
Dim existQuote As Long
For Each xlCell In checkRange
    If xlCell.Value = valueToFind Then

        existQuote = xlCell.Row

        MsgBox (valueToFind & " in row " & existQuote & " has been converted to an order", "Order Conversion Alert: ")


    End If
Next xlCell


Loop Until ActiveCell.Value > 300000 Or ActiveCell.Value = ""
```

Note: This will only work if there are no gaps between data filled cells in the column `ActiveCell` traverses during the `Do` loop. If you have gaps you might want to get a loop-end value from the last row on the sheet with data instead. You could do that like this:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Dim wS As Worksheet
Set wS = ActiveSheet
Dim importWS as worksheet
Dim dataend As Long
Dim counter As Long
importWS = sheets.("NEWDATA")

select.importWS
dataend = Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row
Range("A1").Select

Do
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
       GoTo newloop

     Dim valueToFind As Long
     valueToFind = ActiveCell.Value
     Dim checkRange As Range
     Set checkRange = wS.Range("D1:D" & EntryRow)

    Dim xlCell As Excel.Range
    Dim existQuote As Long
    For Each xlCell In checkRange
        If xlCell.Value = valueToFind Then

            existQuote = xlCell.Row

            MsgBox (valueToFind & " in row " & existQuote & " has been converted to an order", "Order Conversion Alert: ")


        End If
    Next xlCell


newloop:
counter = counter + 1


Loop Until ActiveCell.Value > 300000 Or counter = dataend

ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select
Dim DataPoints As Integer
DataPoints = ActiveCell.Row
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
```

Comment: a) I've now clarified what I was originally trying to do. I cannot seem to get `xlCell.address` into a variable, that's my primary issue here.
b) This snippet is part of a loop which separates quotes (2*****) from  orders (3*****), hence the use of the offset function. I tried to include only the relevant code but it seems like this may have obfuscated my code.
c) I was under the impression that variables were automatically destroyed at the end of a sub unless they were declared as public or global?

Comment: OK, so do you get an error message at all? Since you've `Dim`ed existQuote as a `Range` don't you need you need to `Set` it to an array? And is .Address an array or a string anyway? From the help file it looks like .Address returns a string value. Try using `.Address(RowAbsolute)` as well. You've still got `existingQuote` as an un-`set` variable too. How does VBA know the content of `existingQuote`, as opposed to the `Dim`ed `existQuote`? You're right about destroying variables, by the way, but I always like to see the command visibly and it can be good practice for other languages.

Comment: One more thing - I wonder: If you don't need to display the full address to the user in the `MsgBox`, why not just use `Dim existQuote As Long, [linebreak] existQuote = xlCell.Row [linebreak] Debug.Print existQuote [linebreak] Exit Sub` See if that picks up the value you need?

Comment: `.address` was returning a string - I think this was the problem as it now works perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: If your question is answered, tick?